# Information Criteria for LASSO with high dimentional data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lasso-regression

I'm using the `LassoLarsIC` package with the bayesian criteria to choose the regularization parameter.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoLarsIC

reg = LassoLarsIC(criterion='bic', fit_intercept=True)
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Although, this model just works in no-high dimensional settings because this function estimates the variance by using the OLS model as default (the `noise_variance` parameter). But this is not the case, so I would like to know how the best way to estimate this variance before use the LassoLarsIC (or another way to do this).

And if I may, can you provide me some intuition about the why of your answer?

Thanks